# How do I make this statement repeat a few times?

Tags: javascript

How do I make this statement repeat a few times? I tried and it works for only the first row but the rest of the row cannot be executed.

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Book Ordering System</title>
    <style>

        body{
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#FF7F50,#008080);
        }
        thead,
        tfoot {
            background-color: skyblue;
        }

        tbody td:nth-child(5) input,
        tbody td:nth-child(6) input,
        tbody td:nth-child(7) input {
            text-align: right;

        }

        tr:hover {
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        td:last-of-type input {
            background-color: silver;
        }

        tfoot,
        tfoot input {
            text-align: right;
        }

        tfoot td:last-of-type input {
            font-size: 18pt;
        }
        table{
            border-style: dashed;
            border-width: medium;
            border-color: #EEE8AA;
        }
        tbody td:nth-child(5) input,
        tbody td:nth-child(6) input{
            background-color: tomato;
        }
        tbody td:nth-child(2) input{
            background-color: #00FF7F;
        }
        tbody td:nth-child(3) input{
            background-color: #EE82EE;
        }
        tbody td > select{
            background-color: #FFA500;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Book Ordering System</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <table border="2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>No.</th>
                    <th>Book Title</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Unit Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">
                        <input type="button"  onclick="multiply();" value="Calculate Grand Total Price">
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="text" name="grandTotal" id="grandTotal" value="0.00" readonly="readonly">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec1"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec1" id="sec1" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec2"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec2" id="sec2" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="category" id="category">
                            <option value="choose">Please choose the category...</option>
                            <option value="biz">Business</option>
                            <option value="fiction">Fiction</option>
                            <option value="maths">Mathematics</option>
                            <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec3"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec3" id="sec3" value="0.00" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec4"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec4" id="sec4" value="0" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec5"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec5" id="sec5" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec1"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec6" id="sec6" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec2"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec7" id="sec7" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="category" id="category">
                            <option value="choose">Please choose the category...</option>
                            <option value="biz">Business</option>
                            <option value="fiction">Fiction</option>
                            <option value="maths">Mathematics</option>
                            <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <label for="sec3"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec8" id="sec8" value="0.00" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec4"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec9" id="sec9" value="0" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec5"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec10" id="sec10" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec1"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec11" id="sec11" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec2"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec12" id="sec12" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="category" id="category">
                            <option value="choose">Please choose the category...</option>
                            <option value="biz">Business</option>
                            <option value="fiction">Fiction</option>
                            <option value="maths">Mathematics</option>
                            <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec3"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec13" id="sec13" value="0.00" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec4"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec14" id="sec14" value="0" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec5"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec15" id="sec15" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec1"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec16" id="sec16" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec2"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec17" id="sec17" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="category" id="category">
                            <option value="choose">Please choose the category...</option>
                            <option value="biz">Business</option>
                            <option value="fiction">Fiction</option>
                            <option value="maths">Mathematics</option>
                            <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec3"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec18" id="sec18" value="0.00" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec4"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec19" id="sec19" value="0" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec5"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec20" id="sec20" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec1"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec21" id="sec21" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec2"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec22" id="sec22" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="category" id="category">
                            <option value="choose">Please choose the category...</option>
                            <option value="biz">Business</option>
                            <option value="fiction">Fiction</option>
                            <option value="maths">Mathematics</option>
                            <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec3"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec23" id="sec23" value="0.00" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec4"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec24" id="sec24" value="0" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec5"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec25" id="sec25" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
    <script>
        function multiply(){

            let num1 = document.getElementById("sec3").value ;
            let num2 = document.getElementById("sec4").value ;
            document.getElementById("sec5").value = num1 * num2;

            num1 = document.getElementById("sec8").value ;
            num2 = document.getElementById("sec9").value ;
            document.getElementById("sec10").value = num1 * num2;

            num1 = document.getElementById("sec13").value ;
            num2 = document.getElementById("sec14").value ;
            document.getElementById("sec15").value = num1 * num2;

            num1 = document.getElementById("sec18").value ;
            num2 = document.getElementById("sec19").value ;
            document.getElementById("sec20").value = num1 * num2;

            num1 = document.getElementById("sec23").value ;
            num2 = document.getElementById("sec24").value ;
            document.getElementById("sec25").value = num1 * num2;

            total = document.getElementById("sec5").value + document.getElementById("sec10").value + document.getElementById("sec15").value
                    + document.getElementById("sec20").value + document.getElementById("sec25").value ;

            document.getElementById("grandTotal").value = total;
        }
       </script>
</body>

</html>
```

How do I make this statement repeat a few times? I tried and it works for only the first row but the rest of the row cannot be executed. It only functions in the 1st row

Comment: you may have to give table information as well so that we can understand which rows and columns you are talking about.

Comment: Seems that jQuery can help here. Use ```each()``` function on ```table > tbody > tr``` selector to apply your ```multiply()``` function.

Comment: `How do I make this statement repeat a few times ?` how we suppose to understand which statement you want repetitive. you mention this line 2 times but you never mention which line of code.

Comment: @WaytoDeveloper I think the above problem is solved. However, I still have an issue adding the final total price together. The value still would not change for the final total price.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you applying a reload button

```
<FORM>
 <INPUT TYPE="button" onClick="history.go(0)" VALUE="Refresh">
</FORM>
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing your code with this:

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Book Ordering System</title>
    <style>

        body{
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#FF7F50,#008080);
        }
        thead,
        tfoot {
            background-color: skyblue;
        }

        tbody td:nth-child(5) input,
        tbody td:nth-child(6) input,
        tbody td:nth-child(7) input {
            text-align: right;

        }

        tr:hover {
            background-color: yellow;
        }

        td:last-of-type input {
            background-color: silver;
        }

        tfoot,
        tfoot input {
            text-align: right;
        }

        tfoot td:last-of-type input {
            font-size: 18pt;
        }
        table{
            border-style: dashed;
            border-width: medium;
            border-color: #EEE8AA;
        }
        tbody td:nth-child(5) input,
        tbody td:nth-child(6) input{
            background-color: tomato;
        }
        tbody td:nth-child(2) input{
            background-color: #00FF7F;
        }
        tbody td:nth-child(3) input{
            background-color: #EE82EE;
        }
        tbody td > select{
            background-color: #FFA500;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Book Ordering System</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <table border="2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>No.</th>
                    <th>Book Title</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Unit Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">
                        <input type="button"  onclick="multiply();" value="Calculate Grand Total Price">
                    </td>
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <input type="text" name="grandTotal" id="grandTotal" value="0.00" readonly="readonly">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec1"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec1" id="sec1" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec2"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec2" id="sec2" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="category" id="category">
                            <option value="choose">Please choose the category...</option>
                            <option value="biz">Business</option>
                            <option value="fiction">Fiction</option>
                            <option value="maths">Mathematics</option>
                            <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec3"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec3" id="sec3" value="0.00" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec4"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec4" id="sec4" value="0" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec5"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec5" id="sec5" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec1"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec6" id="sec6" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec2"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec7" id="sec7" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="category" id="category">
                            <option value="choose">Please choose the category...</option>
                            <option value="biz">Business</option>
                            <option value="fiction">Fiction</option>
                            <option value="maths">Mathematics</option>
                            <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <label for="sec3"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec8" id="sec8" value="0.00" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec4"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec9" id="sec9" value="0" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec5"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec10" id="sec10" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec1"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec11" id="sec11" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec2"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec12" id="sec12" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="category" id="category">
                            <option value="choose">Please choose the category...</option>
                            <option value="biz">Business</option>
                            <option value="fiction">Fiction</option>
                            <option value="maths">Mathematics</option>
                            <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec3"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec13" id="sec13" value="0.00" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec4"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec14" id="sec14" value="0" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec5"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec15" id="sec15" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec1"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec16" id="sec16" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec2"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec17" id="sec17" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="category" id="category">
                            <option value="choose">Please choose the category...</option>
                            <option value="biz">Business</option>
                            <option value="fiction">Fiction</option>
                            <option value="maths">Mathematics</option>
                            <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec3"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec18" id="sec18" value="0.00" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec4"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec19" id="sec19" value="0" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec5"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec20" id="sec20" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec1"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec21" id="sec21" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec2"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec22" id="sec22" value="" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="category" id="category">
                            <option value="choose">Please choose the category...</option>
                            <option value="biz">Business</option>
                            <option value="fiction">Fiction</option>
                            <option value="maths">Mathematics</option>
                            <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec3"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec23" id="sec23" value="0.00" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec4"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec24" id="sec24" value="0" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label for="sec5"></label>
                        <input type="text" name="sec25" id="sec25" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
    <script>
        function multiply(){

            let total = 0;

            let num1 = document.getElementById("sec3").value ;
            let num2 = document.getElementById("sec4").value ;
            document.getElementById("sec5").value = num1 * num2;
            total += (num1 * num2);
            num1 = document.getElementById("sec8").value ;
            num2 = document.getElementById("sec9").value ;
            document.getElementById("sec10").value = num1 * num2;
            total += (num1 * num2);
            num1 = document.getElementById("sec13").value ;
            num2 = document.getElementById("sec14").value ;
            document.getElementById("sec15").value = num1 * num2;
            total += (num1 * num2);
            num1 = document.getElementById("sec18").value ;
            num2 = document.getElementById("sec19").value ;
            document.getElementById("sec20").value = num1 * num2;
            total += (num1 * num2);
            num1 = document.getElementById("sec23").value ;
            num2 = document.getElementById("sec24").value ;
            document.getElementById("sec25").value = num1 * num2;
            total += (num1 * num2);

            document.getElementById("grandTotal").value = total;
        }
       </script>
</body>

</html>
```

*EDIT:* this should work by now

Comment: this will work, but please do compare this codes to yours and study them, every id must be unique (also names if possible). I just changed those IDs and add the javascript.

Comment: it works well but my total price cannot be updated. I tried adding it together but the total price turn into a string instead of adding it up together. So, I updated my code on top for u to check on the problem

Comment: sure, just ask anytime, you can accept this as a valid answer now. Thanks @Kingdom452